# How long does it take for apple to review your message in resolution center

Tags: ios, process, appstore-approval, review

My iphone app rejected due to screen shot containing placeholder iAd banner.  I loaded a new screen shot without the iAd banner and replied the message in resolution center.  However, since it is only meta data change and doesn't require a new binary.  The status is still reject.  My question is how long will it take for apple to read my message and review it again. Anyone has experience like this?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming at all

Answer (score 7):

Usually they resume your review the next business day

Answer (score 4):

had that experience just last week.  They picked it up and carried on with the review in a little under 24 hours.

Comment: Suggest you select "accept answer" :)  welcome to SO!